# FXML and Controller in different packages - Button onAction issue

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I'm new to JavaFX and currently having some trouble working with onAction events with classes within different packages.

Here is the package tree :

[image]

Here is the sample of code that is not working :

```
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<GridPane fx:controller="GUIController.AccueilController" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">

    ...

    <HBox spacing="10" alignment="bottom_right" 
        GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
        <Button text="Se connecter" onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"/>
    </HBox>

    ...

</GridPane>
```

The error is sent by :

```
onAction="#handleSubmitButtonAction"
```

Saying : "Handler method is not accessible. Make public, or annotate with @FXML"

Here is the AccueilController.java file :

```
package GUIController;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class AccueilController {

    @FXML private Text actiontarget;

    @FXML protected void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        actiontarget.setText("Sign in button pressed");
    }

}
```

As you can see, the @FXML tag has been added, so I don't know where the problem is. It may be a bit dumb, but I really can't figure it out.

By the way, without the onAction line, the code is working perfectly.

Thank you guys !

Comment: change protected void handleSubmitButtonAction to public method

Comment: This doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing `import java.awt.event.ActionEvent` with `import javafx.event.ActionEvent`. JavaFX probably tries to call your method with another type of argument and can't find a suitable overloaded method.

Comment: oh wow it's kinda amazing this little thing stumped me for about an hour...good thing i found this.